# RAM usage in dealing with numpy arrays and Python lists

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, google-colaboratory

I have memory issues and can't understand why. I'm using Google Colab, that gives me 12GB of RAM and let me see how the RAM usage is.

I'm reading `np.array` from files, and loading each array in a list.

```
database_list = list()
for filename in glob.glob('*.npy'):
  temp_img = np.load(filename)
  temp_img = temp_img.reshape((-1, 64)).astype('float32')
  temp_img = cv2.resize(temp_img, (64, 3072), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
  database_list.append(temp_img)
```

The code `print("INTER_LINEAR: %d bytes" % (sys.getsizeof(database_list)))` prints:

> INTER_LINEAR: 124920 bytes

It is the same value for arrays reshaped as 64x64, 512x64, 1024x64, 2048x64 and for 3072x64. But if I reshape these arrays as 4096x64, I get an error, for too much RAM used.

With arrays of 3072x64 I can see the RAM usage get higher and higher and then going back down.

My final goal is to zero-padding each array to a dimension of 8192x64, but my session crash before; but this is another problem.

How is the RAM used? Why, if the arrays have different dimensions, the list has the same size? How python is loading and manipulating this file, that explains the RAM usage history?

EDIT:

Does then

```
sizeofelem = database_list[0].nbytes 
#all arrays have now the same dimensions MxN, so despite its content, they should occupy the same memory
total_size = sizeofelem * len(database_list)
```

work and `total_size`reflects the correct size of the list?

Comment: Because the data, which holds the contents of each numpy array, is held in a separately allocated block of memory. The array object itself is just a bunch of metadata, and pointer to the data buffer, and as such is always the same (small) size.

Comment: @DanMašek I have added an edit; can you respond to that? And then I will close the question. I would apppreciate very much if you can explain your answer more thoroughly, even if it is clear right now. Thank you

Comment: What you calculate in the edit is a total size of the memory used by the contents of the arrays. It doesn't include the array metadata, nor anything related to the list. However, a 4096x64 array of 32bit floats is 1 MiB, so just using `total_size` will easily give you an estimate correct to < 0.1%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution.

First of all, as [Dan Mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek) pointed out, I'm measuring the memory used by the array, which is a collection of pointers (roughly said). To measure the real memory usage:

```
(database_list[0].nbytes * len(database_list) / 1000000, "MB")
```

where `database_list[0].nbytes` is reliable as all the elements in `database_list` have the same size. To be more precise, I should add the array metadata and eventually all data linked to it (if, for example, I'm storing in the array other structures).

To have less impact on memory, I should know the type of data that I'm reading, that is values in range 0-65535, so:

```
database_list = list()
for filename in glob.glob('*.npy'):
  temp_img = np.load(filename)
  temp_img = temp_img.reshape((-1, 64)).astype(np.uint16)
  database_list.append(temp_img)
```

Moreover, if I do some calculations on the data stored in database_list, for example, normalization of values in the range 0-1 like `database_list = database_list/ 65535.0` (NB: database_list, as a list, does not support that operation), I should do another cast, because Python cast the type to something like float64.